# Intro.js does not working with React and Remix.run

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, remix.run, intro.js

I'm trying to create onboarding modals on header links with intro.js . I'm using intro.js package in React.

Here's the code:

```
import { useState, type FC } from 'react'
import type { Links } from '../types'
import 'intro.js/introjs.css'
import { Steps } from 'intro.js-react'

export const Test = () => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
  const [initialStep, setInitialStep] = useState(0)

  const onExit = () => {
    setEnabled(false)
  }

  const steps = [
    {
      element: '#test1',
      intro: 'You can use this button for help',
      position: 'right',
    },
    {
      element: '#test2',
      intro: 'You can use this button to get more information',
    },
    {
      element: '#test3',
      intro: 'You can use this button to contact us',
    },
  ]

  return (
    <ul className='text-black-primary font-medium text-base flex gap-3 items-center max-md:text-white max-md:block'>
      <Steps enabled={enabled} steps={steps} initialStep={initialStep} onExit={onExit} />
      <div className='flex gap-5'>
        <p className='m-1' id='test1'>
          test1
        </p>
        <p className='m-1' id='test2'>
          test2
        </p>
        <p className='m-1' id='test3'>
          test3
        </p>
        <p
          className='m-1'
          id='test4'
          onClick={() => {
            console.log('test')
            setEnabled(true)
          }}
        >
          test4
        </p>
      </div>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Interesting part is that I've tried this library with fresh `create-react-app` and it worked fine. But with my existing project 1st issue I've faced was could not resolve `intro.js/introjs.css`, after installing intro.js it dissapeared, but again, fresh react-app had no issues. And the main one is that it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue could be that the CSS file for `intro.js` is not being loaded correctly.You can import the CSS file like this:

```js
import 'intro.js/introjs.css';
```

Make sure that you have installed both `intro.js` and `intro.js-react` using npm. You can install them like this:

```bash
npm install intro.js intro.js-react
```

Comment: I've installed both packages, and doing the same import. My theory is that this lib does work with SSR pretty bad, coz it does work in one route(still with UI bugs), but does not work anywhere else

Comment: UPD: just tried with fresh Remix.run app. SSR is not the case, does work fine. Idk where the problem can be now..

Comment: @Даниил If the issue is not related to SSR, then it’s possible that there is an issue with your existing project. You mentioned that you are seeing UI bugs when using the intro.js-react library. Can you provide more details about what kind of UI bugs you are seeing

Comment: well, there were darkened background, smth like white outline but with mismatched width and height, so it was x5 times bigger then it should be. Also originally there should be a modal with text and button next/prev, but it looked like modal styles were not applied so text+buttons were like plain html

Comment: Probably there is an issue with styles, coz clicking button applies style from intro.js package, it simply does nothing